# After mapping Caps Lock to Escape using xmodmap, how to revert Caps Lock back to Caps Lock without altering Escape key?

Tags: x11, xmodmap

I have mapped my Caps Lock key to function as Escape using this command.

```
xmodmap -e "remove Lock = Caps_Lock" -e "keysym Caps_Lock = Escape"
```

Now how can I undo this mapping? I tried the following but apart from reverting Caps Lock key to function as Caps Lock, it also sets Escape key to function as Caps Lock.

```
xmodmap -e "keysym Escape = Caps_Lock" -e "add Lock = Caps_Lock"
```

Is there a way to revert only Caps Lock key to function as Escape while leaving the Escape key intact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before doing your first change you must note the **keycode** you are changing. Eg

```
$ xmodmap -pke|grep Caps_Lock
keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
```

Then use this keycode to restore just that key, not all keys with keysym "Escape". Eg:

```
$ xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock"
```

66 is what my keyboard has, yours may not be the same.

Comment: Thank you. It was 66 on my system too. I have a related question now that I have posted at http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/226843/131209.