# Why does Caps Lock key behave as Caps Lock key without the Lock modifier?

Tags: x11, xmodmap

At first, there is no key mapping. The Caps Lock key on my keyboard behaves as Caps Lock.

```
lone@debian:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep Caps_Lock
keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
lone@debian:~$ xmodmap -pm | grep lock
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
```

Then I remap my Caps Lock key to function as Escape key.

```
lone@debian:~$ xmodmap -e "remove Lock = Caps_Lock" -e "keycode 66 = Escape"
lone@debian:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep Caps_Lock
lone@debian:~$ xmodmap -pm | grep lock
lock
```

Now when I press the Caps Lock key, I see it behaving like Escape key. I tested this in vi editor.

Now I map the Caps Lock key to behave again as Caps Lock key.

```
lone@debian:~$ xmodmap -e "keycode 66 = Caps_Lock"
lone@debian:~$ xmodmap -pke | grep Caps_Lock
keycode  66 = Caps_Lock NoSymbol Caps_Lock
lone@debian:~$ xmodmap -pm | grep lock
lock
```

Now when I press the Caps Lock key, it indeed behaves as Caps Lock. My question is: Why wasn't it necessary to perform `add Lock = Caps_Lock` again to make the Caps Lock key behave as Caps Lock.

The above output shows that there is no key set to 'lock' modifier. How is it that the Caps Lock key behaves like Caps Lock key then?

Comment: `xmodmap` is not telling you the whole truth, you may have XKB mappings on top. Have a look at `setxkbmap -query`, `setxkbmap -print` and `xkbcmp`.

Comment: That's a very interesting question! I've been reading about how some of the X11 key handling works and ShiftLockMask (XK_Caps_Lock) is one of the clearly defined parts of the X11 keyboard spec. Compare that to the Win/Cmd/Super/Hyper keys that might be mod1 - mod4... I think we probably have to run through each of these in the debugger to find out exactly what's happening though.